# Is there a restriction on the length of WPA passwords in Lubuntu?

Tags: networking, lubuntu, network-manager, password

I'm having a strange Wi-Fi issue in Lubuntu (live USB).

It can see my Wi-Fi network, but after I enter the password and click connect, it tries for about 30 seconds and ends with the message I'm disconnected.

My network is using WPA2 and works with all of my other devices.
After reading through some posts here I tried:

```
sudo leafpad /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

I added the line:

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

After this I restarted the service with:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

I still couldn't get connected. To test, I set up a Wi-Fi hotspot on my phone and it connected flawlessly. The only differences I can see are that my home Wi-Fi is using a 20 character ASCII password and the hotspot is using 12 characters.

My next step will be to change the Wi-Fi password on my router once everyone is done using it to rule out if the issue is actually the password length or some other problem.

In the meantime I'd like to know if there is a restriction in Network-Manager in regards to password length? If so, is there a way around this?

Comment: I don't believe that Ubuntu nor Network Manager differ from the published standard of 8 to 63 characters. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18006390/why-is-the-wpa2-psk-key-length-limited-to-63-characters Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: You haven't said what release of Lubuntu (Lubuntu has upgraded from *near dead* LXDE to *very active* LXQt) but it's wireless software is base Ubuntu (thus NetworkManager).  What are you running?  I assume an older version (last three releases haven't used `leafpad`)

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. Sorry, I forgot to add, it's 16.04.3 LTS.  The ISO has been sitting on my drive for a while. So would 19.04 possibly resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I just booted up to the 19.04 desktop, entered my wifi pw and got connected with no problems.

So all is good now. If anyone has any idea why it didn't work in 16.04.3 please let me know, just to sate my curiosity.

Thanks everyone. I think I'll enjoy this community.

Goodbye Windows! Again...